# How to be notified for high costs of queries in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a project in BigQuery where many people update/add Views.
Other access Views/Tables from 3rd party softwares like Tableau.

I have no control for example if the Analysit who wrote the query in Tableau used the Partition of the table or not.

Is it possible somehow to ask BigQuery to send email for each query that passes threshold? For example 20GB. Then I can check this specific query and user to see if it's OK or not (I'm not forcing partition as it's not always what we need)

I know that it's possible to use the Stackdriver Logging export to download logs into BigQuery tables / storage but I don't see anything there that can tell me if query passed this specific criteria.

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions available but the best is using Cloud Pub/Sub topics and piece of Cloud Function:

- [Enable programmatic notifications to receive Cloud Pub/Sub messages with the current status of your budget](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets)
- [Programmatic Budgets Notification Examples](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify)

Comment: This is not really what I'm after. This gives you warrning when you are about to cross the budget limit. It doesn't help you to investigate why. I'm more looking to something like this: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/3-ways-to-detect-slow-queries-in-postgresql/   in PostgreSQL you can monitor slow queries. get the exact transaction that is slow and who is the user running it. Then you are focus to investigate this specific query - You don't need to find it in a giant list of sessions. It already gives you what you want to see.

Comment: There is no tailored solution for that yet. You need to wire in your logic. So export ALL then alert on SOME. And this needs to be coded by you.